# Parallel numerical integration using python

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing, numerical-integration

I would like to numerically integration a function using multiple cpus in python. I would like to do something like:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import multiprocessing
def FanDDW(arguments):
  wtq,eigq_files,DDB_files,EIGR2D_files,FAN_files = arguments
  ...
  return tot_corr

# Numerical integration
def integration(frequency):
# Parallelize the work over cpus
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nb_cpus)
  total = pool.map(FanDDW, zip(wtq,eigq_files,DDB_files,EIGR2D_files,FAN_files))
  FanDDW_corr = sum(total)
  return quad(FanDDW, -Inf, Inf, args=(zip(wtq,eigq_files,DDB_files,EIGR2D_files,FAN_files)))[0]

vec_functionint = vectorize(integration)
vec_functionint(3,arange(1.0,4.0,0.5))
```

Also "frequency" is a global variable (external to FanDDW(arguments)). It is a vector containing the position where the function must be evaluated. I guess that quad should choose frequency in a clever way. How to pass it to FanDDW knowing that it should NOT be distributed among CPUs and that pool.map does exactly that (it is the reason why I did put it as a global variable and did not pass it to the definition as argument).

Thank you for any help.

Samuel.

Answer (score 0):

All classical quadrature rules have the form

[image]

The computation of the `f(x_i)` is typically the most costly, so if you want to use multiple CPUs, you'll have to think about how to design your `f`. The sum can be expressed as a scalar product `<w, f(x_i)>`, and when using `numpy.dot` for it, it uses threading on most architectures.

[quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine) calls your integrand with all points and once, so in `f` you have to chance to get fancy with the computations.

```py
import quadpy


def f(x):
    print(x.shape)  # (1, 50)
    return x[0] ** 2


scheme = quadpy.e1r2.gauss_hermite(50)
val = scheme.integrate(f)

print(val)  # 0.886226925452758
```